# Multivariate normal probability of being inside ellipse

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, normal-distribution, conic-sections

> Assume that $\mathbf{X}$ is a bivariate normal random variable $$\mathbf{\mu} = E\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \  \text{and} \ \Sigma = Cov \ \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$
>
> What is the probability that $\mathbf{X}$ falls within the elipse corresponding to $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\mu}) = 4.6 ?$

[image]

So Im assuming I need to calculate the probability of $x_1$ lying between $x_1$ min and $x_1$ max, and likewise for $x_2$? However Im not sure how to do this calculation seeing as the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not independent. It also seems like the endpoints of the ellipse do not match my calculations. I believe the ellipse should have half axe lengths $\sqrt{\lambda_i b}$ and its centered at $\mathbf{\mu}$. So according to my calculations $x_1$ should lie between -4.28 and +4.28 which seems incorrect from graphical inspection.

Comment: The random vector $\Sigma^{-1/2} (x-\mu)$ has distribution $N(0,I)$, so your example correspond to looking at probability that standard normal $N(0,I)$ is in the circle of radius $\sqrt{4.6}$

Comment: How would you go about calculating the probability of the standard normal being inside the circle? Also Im assuming the circle is centered at $\mu$?

Comment: Not sure what is being asked. Is it the probability $P\left[(\mathbf X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf X-\mu)\le 4.6\right]$? Then you have $(\mathbf X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf X-\mu)\sim \chi^2_2$ by a general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $U=\Sigma^{-1/2}(x-\mu)\sim \mathcal N(0,I)$ so you look at $\mathbb P(U\in \mathcal C)$ with $\mathcal C = \{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2\leq r^2 \}$. You can compute this by doing the change of coordinate from Cartesian to polar :
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathcal C} dp_{U} &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r a \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-a^2/2) da d\theta\\
&= -\exp(-a^2/2) \bigg|_0^r\\
&= 1-\exp(-r^2/2)
\end{align*}
If you plug in $r=\sqrt{4.6}$ you get approximately $0.8997412$.